# ASP.NET MVC Refreshing other fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to implement a dropdown list to a page. Ii binds correctly after I click the submit button but I want to update another field after picking a option from the list.

```
Controller Class:

public class AddOrderController : Controller
{
    private readonly AddOrderModel _addorder;
    private readonly IProductsRepository _products;
    

    public OrderDetailsModel Orderdetails { get; }

    public AddOrderController(IOrderDetailsRepository orderrepository, AddOrderModel addorder, IProductsRepository products)
    {
        _addorder = addorder;
        _products = products;
        
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(_addorder);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(AddOrderModel order) 
    {
        return View(order);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PriceRefresh(AddOrderModel order)
    {
        var unitprice = await _products.GetSingleUnitPriceAsync(order.ProductId);
        order.UnitPrice = unitprice.HasValue ? decimal.Round(unitprice.Value, 2) : decimal.Zero;
        return View("Index",order);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model AddOrderModel
@inject IOrderDetailsRepository orderdetails
@inject SelectListItemState selecteditems

    <form method="post" asp-controller="AddOrder" asp-action="Index" role="form">
    <div>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    @{
                        var orderId = (orderdetails.GetOrdersIDAsync().Result.Max() + 1);
    
                        <td><label asp-for="@Model.OrderId"></label></td>
                        <td><label> @orderId</label></td>
                        <td><input asp-for="@Model.OrderId" value="@orderId" hidden="hidden" /></td>
                    }
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label asp-for="@Model.Quantity"></label></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.Quantity" /></td>
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Product name</label></td>
                    <td>
                        
                        <select asp-for="@Model.ProductId" asp-items="@selecteditems.ListElements.Result"></select>
                    </td>
    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label asp-for="@Model.UnitPrice"></label></td>
                    <td><label> @Model.UnitPrice</label></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.UnitPrice" value="@Model.UnitPrice" hidden="hidden" /></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" asp-action="PriceRefresh" name="prodid" value="Refresh The Price"></input></td>
                </tr>
            
        </table>
    </div>
    
    </br>
    
    <div>
            @* makes post request to controller in the form *@
            <input type="submit" value="Add order" asp-action="Index"></input>
        </div>
    </form>
```

State Class:

```
public class SelectListItemState
{
    private readonly IProductsRepository _products;
    public Task<List<SelectListItem>>? ListElements { get; set; }
    public SelectListItemState(IProductsRepository products)
    {
        _products = products;
        ListElements = PupulateListElements();
    }

    public async Task<List<SelectListItem>> PupulateListElements()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> listofElements = new();
        var listofproducts = _products.GetProductsNameAsync().Result.ToList();

        listofElements.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Select" });
        foreach (var productname in listofproducts)
        {
            var prodid = await Task.FromResult(_products.MatchProductIdAsync(productname)).Result;
            listofElements.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = prodid.ToString(), Text = productname });
        }
        return listofElements;
    }

}
```

I have tried everything I know and this is the current state of the View. I know that I am doing something wrong but can't figure what.

Comment: Can't reproduce your project, please provide enough code. BTW  I don't suggest you to write so many logic in your view code.

Comment: Hey, yes the View was suposed to be refactored but i wanted to test it in one place. So the trouble I am having here is that after i pick the option from the list my price is not refreshing automaticaly. I did add a button for manual refresh. It works fine and binds the objec but i want the price to refresh automaticaly after i pick an item and can't figure it out on my own.

Comment: Or you can just provide a github about your project, It will save me a lot of time to reproduce your project.

Comment: I can't share the project but i did soem testing and i need to use Some Java script and unfortuantly i am not familliar with it. The simplest way is to use "onchange" in select and then invokwe the PriceRefresh Action that i have in the controller.And i do not know how to do that..

Answer (score 0):

So i actualy managed to solve my problem. i have Made updates in :

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="AddOrder" asp-action="PriceRefresh" role="form">
<div>
    <table>
            <tr>
                @{
                    var orderId = (orderdetails.GetOrdersIDAsync().Result.Max() + 1);

                            <td><label asp-for="@Model.OrderId"></label></td>
                            <td><label> @orderId</label></td>
                            <td><input asp-for="@Model.OrderId" value="@orderId" hidden="hidden" /></td>
                }
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label asp-for="@Model.Quantity"></label></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.Quantity" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label>Product name</label></td>
                <td>
                    @* asp-for is is needed to properly map the value from option *@
                    <select asp-for="@Model.ProductId" asp-items="@selecteditems.ListElements.Result" onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>
                </td>
        
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label asp-for="@Model.UnitPrice"></label></td>
                <td><label> @Model.UnitPrice</label></td>
                <td><input asp-for="@Model.UnitPrice" value="@Model.UnitPrice" hidden="hidden" /></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</br>

<div>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Add order" asp-controller="AddOrder" asp-action="SaveData"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

The changes were:

- diffrent controller that only refreshes the @Model.UnitPrice
- diffrent controlled for saving data in the database
- also i am using onchange="this.form.submit()" to actualy re rrender the page when user picks item from the list

It binds perfeclty to a new object so my question is solved :)